# Notification.BigPictureStyle with actions not rendered correctly on Samsung Galaxy S III

Tags: android, notifications

I'm struggling with this issue on SGS III. My app works well on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7 but on SGS III there are actions not rendered correctly. See attached picture.

Anybody has any idea how to fix it?

Please note that bitmap is 450 * displayDensity wide and 450/2 * displayDensity high.

[image: Incorrect display of Notification.BigPictureStyle with actions on Samsung Galaxy SIII]

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with custom RemoteViews emulating standard look. Not nice solution but gave me way how to add more than three actions too.